# How to add emoticons on facebook wall and comments

Tags: facebook, emoticons

I wonder what tricks this page use to post emoticons
https://www.facebook.com/Animated.Pictures

I check the json data, it contains:

```
"message": "Quote of The Day :\r\n\r\n\udbba\udf4a Love isn't something you find. \udbb8...
```

I suspect the `\uddba\udf4a` is emoticon code. But when I directly post this code in comment box, it doesnt work.

Question:
**Am I missing something or this is the facebook flaws?**

Comment: @Adel that has nothing to do with what he is asking...

Comment: I tried posting emoji to Facebook using my iPhone (iOS 5 has an emoji keyboard). They show up fine on iOS devices, and on Chrome they only appear in the title bar- not in the page's body. So it's not exactly this, but I suspect the page you link uses something somewhat like this (maybe a subset of emojis work on FB properly?)

Answer (score 1):

From last friday (2012-10-05) onwards, Facebook allows displaying your emoticons in its comment box. Usually we will make some special combinations to express it as like smiley. By the silent update made by FB hereafter similar to your FB Chat box you can display emoticons in your comment box. I have provided some bizarre emoticons in my blog post. http://techmites.com/insert-like-button-in-facebook/

Comment: Could you please add more details to your answer? If your blog goes away, all readers will have is a dead link.

Comment: Please check your Facebook account and insert some common smiley combinations to display your emoticon as if you do in your chat-box. you can now get your comment-box. This is what I meant in my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug with Facebook (can't see the link you provided above...must have been removed).  Usually Facebook doesnt allow for animated anything unless it lives inside a canvas app (even then they do strongly discourage it!)